# Bash to python script conversion

Tags: python, bash, usb, usb-drive, converters

I have a bash script to detect HDD connected in USB. I would like to convert it in python script to use it into SSH connection.

```
#!/bin/bash

for disk in /dev/sd?
do
        detect=$(udevadm info $disk | grep USB)
        if [[ "$detect" == *USB ]]; then
                echo "$disk is a USBDISK.."
        fi
done
```

I tried that, but it doesn't work. I have a problem with the for loop and with the condition in if statement :

```
import paramiko

for disk in "/dev/sd*" :
        CMD = 'udevadm info %s | grep USB' % disk
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(CMD, get_pty = True)
        detect = stdout.read()
        if detect == '*USB' :
            print "disk is a USBDISK.."
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Be more specific please.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have a problem with the for loop and with the condition in if statement

Comment: `for disk in "/dev/sd*":` iterates the letters of the given string. You should use `glob()` or `os.walk()` to enumerate directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Selcuk mentioned, you are looping through a string  instead than through the contents of the folder. When you do:

```
for disk in "/dev/sd*" :
```

you are looping through the string char by char like in the list `['/','d','e','v','/','s','d','*']`

Python works different to bash when referring to strings and paths. Take a look to this answer from [ghostdog74](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) to see how loop through a directory content.

This could fix the problems with the `if` condition. As a recommendation, you might consider if you want to check in the condition for:
 Exact string:

```
if detect == '*USB' :
```

or for string inclusion:

```
if '*USB' in detect:
```